# What function of M would always yield an odd square?

Tags: functions

Suppose M is an natural number. what function of M would always yield an odd square, such as 9 or 25, only when M is a triangular number?

Answer (score 1):

A [triangular number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number) is given as $T_n=\frac{n(n+1)}2$, n integer.

A requested odd square is given as $S_{n}=S_{k+1}=(2k+1)^2$, k integer plus zero.

We are requested to have $f(T_n)=S_{k+1} \to f(\frac{n(n+1)}2)=(2k+1)^2
 \to f(\frac{n^2+n}2)=4k^2+4k+1=8\frac{k^2+k}{2}+1$.

Hence it is enough to take $f(M)=8M+1$ for having $f(T_n)=S_n$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $f(n) = n(n+1)/2$ be the rule of the function that maps from the counting numbers to the triangular numbers.  $f(.)$ is one-to-one.  Let $g(n)=(2n+1)^2$ be the rule that maps from the counting numbers to the odd squares, starting with $g(1)=9$. $g(.)$ too is one-to-one.
$$
f^{-1}(x)=\frac{-1+\sqrt{1+8x}}{2}
$$
so
$$
h(x)=g(f^{-1}(x))=1+8x
$$
will do the trick.  It is guaranteed to produce an odd square for every triangular number, and it will never produce an odd square for any other number because $f^{-1}(.)$ is an increasing function defined on the counting numbers, and it assumes integer values only for the triangular numbers.